# How to Achieve in Visual Force Page?

Tags: visualforce, custom-object

Can any one help me out .How to achieve this page in Visual force pages.Whether i need to create a custom object and call the field[image]s in Visual force page or use some javascripts .Any Suggestion plz.

PFA Screen Shot

Comment: If the question is about how to make an header cell span over more than a column, you have to go for a custom-written table (i.e. not a pageblocktable automated generated table) and read more in here to learn how to build the table you need: http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/colspan-html-attribute/. If the question is just about how to center that heading, then: 1) find the appropriate CSS selector matching those cells 2) apply a "text-align: center" CSS rule to them with "!important" (to avoid Javascript overriding).