# How to get 'n' no of rows and columns in a table using visuaforce pages or html or javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript, html5

Can any one help me out how to get this achieved in the below screen shot.I tried using Visual force pages but unable to do it.I shall appreciate your help.Is this the correct way im doing [image]Code  Written is :

-->
                        
            
            -->
            
        
      
        -->

```
   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Opportunitylineitem}" var="oli" columns="2"  >
        <!--<apex:column value="{!oli.Product2}"  />-->
         <apex:column value="{!oli.UnitPrice}" />
        <apex:column value="{!oli.Quantity}" />
       <!-- <apex:column value="{!oli.listprice}" />-->
        <!-- Header Generated automatically -->
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

-->
             
            
            -->
            
        
        
            -->
             
            
            -->
            
        
        
            -->
             
            
            -->
            
        
        
            -->
             
            
            -->
            
        
        
            -->
             
            
            -->
            
        
        
            -->
             
            
            -->
            
        
        
            -->
             
            
            -->
            
        
        
            -->
             
            
            -->

```
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: your screenshot is very low ,can you elaborate it more

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of your other questions shown [here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55625/how-to-achieve-this-requirement-can-i-use-jave-script-css-and-visual-force) and [here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55504/how-to-achieve-in-visual-force-page)

Comment: @Vineeth:I have attached the ScreenShot again.Any suggestion plz

Comment: @BarCotter:Their is a change in the Screenshot compare to the previous post.

Comment: Number of rows = number of records; number of columns is defined by yourself(your code)

Comment: @nikkey Can you explain what object each row in the table is? Is it a custom or standard object? And what child object of that (is it a custom or standard object) are you trying to break out by quarter? And is the date that matters for the quarter on the parent or child object?

Comment: @KeithC:It is a Standard object and child is the custom object.Opportunity object ,with the related list as products.We do have different products with their sales price ,quantity ,list price etc.Now when i click on one of the product name ,it takes me to the product page.In that page we do have Schedule as a related list with their date column ,quantity etc.Now i would like to Dynamically populate the value of pricing request instead of date column.Eg:Opportunity-products-productname-Schedule-Datecolumn -remove datecolumn and dynamically populate the value of  pricing request and quantity.

Comment: @Keith:Creating a custom object as quote line item .The part numbers(Product) with some picklist value ,quarter nos , quantity and price.Based on quote line items can we create a layout like by prepopulating items, price & qty and next 6 qtrs.  
Example below 2 part numbers are there in quote line items, also default the price from quote line item.  Upon saving it should save as detailed record for each quarter.

Comment: @nikkey It looks like you have a number of pieces of work that make up the  overall requirement. This isn't a forum where someone is going to code that for you; you will need to work on it and post specific questions where you get stuck.

Comment: @KeithC:I have posted my code ,which i have tried .Iam completely confused whether it is achievable thru Vf pages tags using repeat tag etc ,or go with html or javascript.

Comment: @nikkey OK. Add a screenshot from the Schema Builder of the two (?) objects involved and some text describing how you want them presented and leave out any other details in this question. Then someone may suggest a controller and page that will get you the output you want. I've retracted my close vote, but do this quickly before the question gets closed. Also make the title and body of the question consistent.

Comment: @KeithC.created a custom object as quote line item  with fields as quantity,price .now i would like to prepopulate items, price & qty and next 6 qtrs. should give the part numbers which are there in quote line items, also default the price from quote line item. Upon saving it should save as detailed record for each quarter.